# Is there an alternative to DVD-Shrink, that can compress a DVD image to a smaller size to fit on a writeable DVD?

Tags: software-recommendation, dvd

Is there a linux alternative to the Windows application DVD-Shrink, that can compress a DVD image to a smaller size to fit on a writeable DVD?

In backing up some DVD's the ripped ISO file size is over 7000MB is there an alternative linux software, similar to Windows "DVD Shrink" that can compress this to fit on a writeable DVD which is about 4000MB

Comment: no updates to that answer yet?

Comment: what was this voted for closing for?

Comment: @cipricus Click on the close button. You'll see a 1 next to 'primarily opinion based'. Also, when you're satisfied with any of the answers, comment here tagging me so that I can award the bounty to it.

Comment: @muru - The relatively new info is on Handbrake, which is in not an alternative to DVDShrink (comment:  *HandBrake will ... not preserve the original DVD structure*); also, I was not able to install it. K9Copy is too KDE oriented and I cannot test it (I am in Xubuntu) and not actively supported. That leaves us with DVD9to5, proposed in the most voted answer: the name means shrink 9GB DVD to 5GB DVD, it should qualify as an alternative. But I have to test it before deciding, maybe editing that answer to bring it forward.

Comment: @cipricus That's okay. I'm just acting as a proxy for you in this matter, since I don't do ripping and can't judge the answers for myself. Ping me in a week, when the bounty expires.

Comment: @muru - chances are that there are no new&better solutions out there. The accepted answer sums that up very well, and if its author choses the win app is because he tested them all i imagine and was forced to conclude to that. hopefully something new will come up in one week, otherwise you may as well give the bounty to that answer, which is not only about dvdshrink

Comment: I've switched away from DVDs to an entertainment system that can play my ripped files. Could this be a solution in your case?

Comment: @MadMike - what I want is to put some 7-9 GB dvds on my laptop's HDD and save some space by shrinking them to 4.5 GB size keeping the menu structure (the way dvdshrink does it)

Comment: Well then your question title is misleading. It suggest, that you need a file that can be read by a DVD-player. But what you really want is smaller files to save space. I suggest to use handbrake and compress your movies to h.264 in a MKV-container.

Comment: @MadMike - this question is clear: i want space but also i want the 4.5 GB format into an iso  because i need all the movie dvd original structure; that is what 'alternative to DVDShrink' means

Comment: Ah, sorry. Missed the "keeping the menu structure"-part. MKV would _theoretically_ allow menus. But there aren't many players (VLC) and no encoders (that I know of) that would support that.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2180393

Comment: I have a _teaser_ on my current Handbrake menu - "DVD-shrink".  But I also saw a blog where they said this option is '_removed_' because they didn't like the resulting quality.  Has anyone got reliable information on that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best one out there is k9copy but I've been having issues with it in 12.10 64bit, a good alternative is dvd95 and there's another app called [xdvdshrink](http://linuxappfinder.com/package/xdvdshrink/) though xdvdshrink's subtitle ripping capabilities seem broken.

Another option for you would be to run dvdshrink through wine. I have been able to do this rather easily, the only thing extra needed is to list your cdrom in your fstab file and then also add the drive in winecfg as well.

Start by running this command:

```
sudo mkdir -v /media/cdrom
```

This will make the directory where your cdrom will be mounted. Then run this command to open fstab with gedit as root.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Here's the fstab line needed to mount the cdrom, simply copy and paste it to the end of your fstab file:

```
# built in CDrom
/dev/sr0    /media/cdrom    auto    ro,noauto,user,exec 0 0
```

Run this command:

```
sudo mount -a
```

Then run:

```
winecfg
```

Here's a picture of where to add drives in winecfg just click the drives tab, then the autodetect button. Then apply, and OK.

[image: winecfg, drives tab]

Comment: any updates to that, some linux solution?

Comment: in Xubuntu 14.04 modifying the fstab was not needed. the dvd is mounted in `media/username` and seen by dvdshrink

Answer (score 8):

The 2 best tools I know of that work are dvd95 and k9copy.
`sudo apt-get install dvd95` or `sudo apt-get install k9copy`
installing k9copy on a non-kde system will pull down a lot of dependencies, which may or may not be an issue with you.

Comment: dvd95 does not work like dvdshrink; k9copy is not available for 14.04, unless we install the reloaded version 3.0.0 from [here](http://k9copy-reloaded.sourceforge.net/#start). -- [How to install k9copy in 12.04?](http://askubuntu.com/q/538217/47206)

Answer (score 4):

**HandBrake**

HandBrake is really good, and this is the tool I recommend.

The download is available at https://handbrake.fr

Better yet, there is a PPA at https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases/

Although the PPA for the most recent release (version 9.9) is for Raring, it works just fine in 14.04.  You can add the HandBrake repository for Raring and install HandBrake in Ubuntu 14.04 as follows:

```
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu raring main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/handbrake.list
echo "# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu raring main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/handbrake.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 816950D8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk
```

**K9Copy**

K9Copy was an excellent tool, but the developer had stopped supporting it years ago.  Apparently another developer has picked up the project just recently (http://k9copy-reloaded.sourceforge.net/#start) and released version 3.0.0, if you want to try it.  I haven't tried it myself, so I do not know if it will work in 14.04.  You will have to build it from scratch, since pre-built packages for the new version are not available yet.

Comment: Handbrake isn't intended to be used for backing up DVDs by transcoding and stripping them.

Comment: LiveWiteBT is right about that.  HandBrake will let you rip the DVD to a different format and size, so you can copy it to a different media, or smaller DVD disk, but it does not preserve the original DVD structure.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to maintain here an updated answer on the programs that I was able to test, discussing the solutions that have been proposed.

I will leave aside **DVDShrink in Wine.**

---

**[DVD9to5 (dvd95)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/dvd95/)** - I have tested it by making a backup of two video-dvds as iso files. (They were both larger than 5 GB and maybe protected).  There is an option to keep the menus, which I suppose means the structure of the original dvd.

[image]

But the iso files were not playable in VLC.

And I think I know why. In fact **DVD95 cannot select and backup more than one track each time** (a confirmation of this [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/dvd95/discussion/544995/thread/43b767f3/#8ad1/281e)).

While it may work ok with dvd movies that have only one such track (have to test that yet) the ones that have multiple tracks will put a big problem. These are dvds with more than a single movie. **When backing up a dvd with multiple tracks the original menus will be lost** because they relate to the other files that will not be copied. Also, subtitles are not usable in this way, and also scrolling does not work. The separate vob files would be playable separately.

In a such case the good part is that you have a better quality of the main video than in the case all the dvd image would have been there (like DVDSrink can do). I noticed in one case that the main video that was selected kept its original size, and all "shrinking" of the image was done only by removing the other tracks. It is not the same image in this way. But if that is not a problem for you (you do not need menus and subtitles) you may use a simple command `dvdbackup -F` (source for this here: [How do I make an ISO copy of a DVD movie?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125809/32012)) and in this way get only the main feature which might very well be smaller than 4.7GB

- **DVD95 may be an alternative only in the case of dvds with a single track.**

---

**[Handbrake](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/handbrake-gtk/)** - [can convert dvd video to MKV](https://askubuntu.com/q/473308/47206) and [to mp4](https://askubuntu.com/a/473520/47206): maybe a good solution to convert (have not tested it yet), but not to 'shrink' dvd images,

[image]

so, **Handbrake is not a DVDShrink alternative.**

---

**[xDVDShrink](http://linuxappfinder.com/package/xdvdshrink/)** (also .deb) - Does **not work on all dvd sources (encrypted etc)**. The dvds tested above were not even accessed, so I tested with 4.7 dvd movie without protection.

**No support for subtitles** is seems (also mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/219798/47206)), one single video title and one single audio channel selectable it looks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I had made also these settings:

[image]

that were **not** followed. No .iso file was to be found on the desktop or elsewhere. But nor the /tmp files had been deleted as set, so I was able to test those. The full dvd files were found in `/tmp/mydvd/BUILD/`, but they can be played with VLC and SMPlayer just as ordinary video files, **without the original dvd structure of menus**. The most severe problem is the **absence of subtitles** (funny in my case as I was testing with a Japanese movie.)

Therefore: **xDVDShrink is NOT an alternative.**

---

I have left aside for a while **k9copy**, which many have recommended in the past, and which, as [already stated](https://askubuntu.com/a/583578/47206) under this question, is considered the real DVDShrink alternative for Ubuntu.

As the initial project is now inactive, there is a new developer that supports a **k9copy-reloaded** version - [HERE](http://tomtomtom.org/k9copy-reloaded/en.html).

I have installed without any problems the latest deb posted there - the Jessie version - in a Kubuntu 15.04-development branch. It has added only 13 new dependencies.

In Ubuntu Unity and any other non-KDE desktops it will come with a lot more KDE dependencies. But that is the problem with many other KDE applications that at some point may be needed for a specific purpose. If your purpose is to backup DVS-s the way DVDShrink does in Windows, then having some KDE dependencies is not such a bad deal.

### k9copy-reloaded looks like a real alternative and for now the only answer to the question.

---

I will update this post as soon as I am able to test more solutions.

Answer (score 2):

K9copy is said(...) to be the best DVD Shrink alternative. The original developer ceased developing K9copy. K9copy-Reloaded is the continuation of K9copy by a new developer. Information:

- New project page: http://k9copy-reloaded.sourceforge.net/
- k9copy-reloaded Debian/Ubuntu Packages: http://tomtomtom.org/k9copy-reloaded/en.html

IMHO it would be valuable to include a review of K9copy-Reloaded in @cipricus great post, I recommend using the Trusty/Utopic or Jessie packages from tomtomtom site. Beware that K9copy is Qt based and is best installed in a KDE environment, other environments possibly need to pull in a lot of dependencies.

Comment: I had left K9copy aside until I installed Kubuntu, and indeed the Jessie version works fine -- even in a development branch Kubuntu 15.04 . It seems that the reloaded k9copy site has been refurbished and improved a lot since I first started my main answer. I expect the debs from there to work as intended - notwithstanding the unavoidable kde dependencies. I will soon test it in Ubuntu Unity and report in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the purpose of the question was to update the answers under the [older one](https://askubuntu.com/q/129891/47206), I will try to maintain here an updated answer on the programs that I was able to test, discussing the solutions that have been proposed.

I will leave aside for now **DVDShrink in Wine.**

---

[For a while](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K9Copy#Development) **k9copy**, which many have recommended in the past, and which, as [already stated](https://askubuntu.com/a/583578/47206) under this question, is considered the real DVDShrink alternative for Ubuntu, was not supported. But, as the initial project is now inactive, there is a new developer that supports a [**k9copy-reloaded** version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/k9copy-reloaded/). Deb packages can be found [HERE](http://tomtomtom.org/k9copy-reloaded/en.html). To add a PPA - look [HERE](https://launchpad.net/~tomtomtom/+archive/ubuntu/k9copy):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tomtomtom/k9copy 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install k9copy
```

I have installed without any problems the latest deb posted there - the Jessie version - in a Kubuntu 15.04-development branch. It has added only 13 new dependencies.

In Ubuntu Unity and any other non-KDE desktops it will come with a lot more KDE dependencies. But that is the problem with many other KDE applications that at some point may be needed for a specific purpose. If your purpose is to backup DVS-s the way DVDShrink does in Windows, then having some KDE dependencies is not such a bad deal.

**k9copy** looks like a real alternative and for now the only answer to the question.

### [image]

---

**Considering other tools that were mentioned on askubuntu and that I was able to test at some point:**

**[DVD9to5 (dvd95)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/dvd95/)** - I have tested it by making a backup of two video-dvds as iso files. (They were both larger than 5 GB and maybe protected).  There is an option to keep the menus, which I suppose means the structure of the original dvd.

[image]

But the iso files were not playable in VLC.

And I think I know why. In fact **DVD95 cannot select and backup more than one track each time** (a confirmation of this [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/dvd95/discussion/544995/thread/43b767f3/#8ad1/281e)).

While it may work ok with dvd movies that have only one such track (have to test that yet) the ones that have multiple tracks will put a big problem. These are dvds with more than a single movie. **When backing up a dvd with multiple tracks the original menus will be lost** because they relate to the other files that will not be copied. Also, subtitles are not usable in this way, and also scrolling does not work. The separate vob files would be playable separately.

In a such case the good part is that you have a better quality of the main video than in the case all the dvd image would have been there (like DVDSrink can do). I noticed in one case that the main video that was selected kept its original size, and all "shrinking" of the image was done only by removing the other tracks. It is not the same image in this way. But if that is not a problem for you (you do not need menus and subtitles) you may use a simple command `dvdbackup -F` (source for this here: [How do I make an ISO copy of a DVD movie?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125809/32012)) and in this way get only the main feature which might very well be smaller than 4.7GB

- **DVD95 may be an alternative only in the case of dvds with a single track.**

---

**[Handbrake](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/handbrake-gtk/)** - [can convert dvd video to MKV](https://askubuntu.com/q/473308/47206) and [to mp4](https://askubuntu.com/a/473520/47206): maybe a good solution to convert (have not tested it yet), but not to 'shrink' dvd images,

[image]

so, **Handbrake is not a DVDShrink alternative.**

---

**[xDVDShrink](http://linuxappfinder.com/package/xdvdshrink/)** (also .deb) - Does **not work on all dvd sources (encrypted etc)**. The dvds tested above were not even accessed, so I tested with 4.7 dvd movie without protection.

**No support for subtitles** is seems (also mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/219798/47206)), one single video title and one single audio channel selectable it looks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I had made also these settings:

[image]

that were **not** followed. No .iso file was to be found on the desktop or elsewhere. But nor the /tmp files had been deleted as set, so I was able to test those. The full dvd files were found in `/tmp/mydvd/BUILD/`, but they can be played with VLC and SMPlayer just as ordinary video files, **without the original dvd structure of menus**. The most severe problem is the **absence of subtitles** (funny in my case as I was testing with a Japanese movie.)

Therefore: **xDVDShrink is NOT an alternative.**

---

I will try to keep this post up to date.

Comment: also concerning Handbrake: it definitely does not back up a DVD Folder but will convert film to an mv4 or an mkv AND more to the point it does not always "see"everything on the disc;   if you have a series for example it will pick one the episodes and possible ignore all the others so not always a great tool. It will do most main features beautifully but that is not the question we are answering here

Answer (score 0):

Handbrake was suggested already but I would put forward another option that may work for you. It is called [xDVDShrink](http://dvdshrink.sourceforge.net/) Please bear in mind that I have not used it myself. Reading the documentation it seems that you have two options of shrinking, letting the program do it for you automatically, or manually selecting a shrink factor. It also seems to maintain the filesystem of the original DVD.

It is available as a tar.gz download from sourceforge. Follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file) to install on your system.

Comment: I was just taking a look at it now and will update the answer. It can also be installed as deb from [here](http://linuxappfinder.com/package/xdvdshrink/). do you know what is the difference between the shrink factors available? they go between 1 and 2, but what do they mean ?

Comment: As I said, I've not used the software myself so I'm not sure what compression ratio the individual factors would use. There is also the option to let the software do the shrinking automatically which would probably use the optimal settings

Comment: does not work on all dvds (as dvdshrink does) and does not have support for keeping the subtitles

Comment: tested and i cannot confirm it as alternative. see details in my answer

Answer (score 0):

There is only one other program that I have been able to find that hasn't already been mentioned and may be worth a look. Its called [Vamps](http://vamps.sourceforge.net/index.htm)

The downside is, that Vamps is not capable to make DVD backups on its own. qVamps is a GUI, which enables the user to select titles from a DVD, uses Vamps for requantization and create a new DVD. qVamps uses dvdauthor for creation of the new DVD's data structures.

Comment: Sorry to be suspicious, but the last release of Vamps was 2006. Can you confirm it is working with Ubuntu 14.04? How did go about installing it?

Comment: `apt-get install vamps`, then `vamps -v  < input.vob > output.vob` ran here. Unfortunately it didn't shrink my 5.8gib vob file enough for a DVD.

Answer (score 0):

*On 18.04 Dec 2018*

Another way to do all this or rather another permutation of tricks is to:

➊ use Vobcopy to rip dvd to a folder

> vobcopy -m

in terminal is all that is required

➋ THEN if you wish to reduce your 7+GiB folder to a 4.3 / 4.4GiB folder use K9copy assistant [K9] or indeed dvdshrink under Wine [since you have already done the rip no need to horse around adding to fstab]

This way is pretty foolproof. I also raced K9copy and dvdshrink and about same time [2 or 3 minutes to do compression]

Answer (score -2):

I have been "backing up" DVD movie titles since about 2005. My typical procedure is:

1. Use the most recent version of DVDfab to remove encryption and copy files to hard drive, in `.vob` form.
2. Then process the `.vob` files through DVD shrink to compress and then write the output to an `.iso` file. Sometimes I use DVD shrink, without compression, to create a `.iso` file.
3. Use DVD burning software to burn the `.iso` file to a DVD, single or double layer.

This worked flawlessly when I used Windows. The result is an exact copy, except possibly for some compression, of the original DVD title. Then I changed to Debian Linux and it didn't work at all until now.

I was able to get DVDfab ver 9321 non-XP, by updating my system using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then opening the package manager and updating all packages. What is most important is updating the wine program to the latest stable version available.

I had to configure Wine to operate in Windows 8 mode to get DVDfab operating properly.

Then I reinstalled DvdShrink; it ran properly until it came to the encoding process, it would progress about 3/4 of the way through and then it would display the following message:

```
dvd shrink error message: 
dvd shrink encountered an error and can not continue
Out of memory
```

Thinking about all the other responses to this problem on the internet, I thought by limiting the CPU speed of the DVDshrink process I might be able to slow the rate at which data is encoded so that it matches the speed at which it can be written to the hard drive.

Linux has a program which does exactly that, it is called CPUlimit you can download it via:

```
sudo apt install cpulimit
```

So I tried DVDshrink again, using CpuLimit for the DVDShrink process. I had to experiment with the slow-down factor, though finally it worked. If I slow down the DVDshrink process to 10% of maximum it will no longer display the memory message.

Answer (score -3):

It is unfortunate that DVDShrink can't be found playable for Linux/Ubuntu. One alternative that I've done is to copy the DVD as an ISO file in my computer and then burn it as it is (without compressing it) onto another (blank) DVD. There are double density blank DVD's out there that you can get. They are more expensive, but for now and until you find another solution, that might work. Back when I had to copy a hard-to-find movie and didn't have DVDShrink, I was using a software called "InfraRecorder" that I found on Download.cnet but I don't know where to find it now. 
After installing Linux Mint, I discovered that it comes with a software that works exactly as InfraRecorder called "Brasero". Give it a try, hope it will give you the utility that you need.
Good luck on your search.

Comment: haven't you looked at the other answers? k9copy **is** the solution, It is indeed only mentioned at the end of my far too fat answer.