# Only MKV format available in HandBrake

Tags: 14.04, dvd, handbrake

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit. I have installed HandBrake rev5474 (i686), which I believe is the latest, and the Ubuntu Restricted Extras. I am able to play DVDs via VLC but when it comes to ripping them, so that I can back them up to my Twonky media server, I have issues.

I launch HandBrake and find that the only format available for me to select is MKV.

When I used to run Handbrake on this machine while I was running Ubuntu 13.10 and lower I had no issues and ****lots of formats (including MP4 which is what I'm really after)** but since reformating and installing 14.04 I've had this issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is [Debian bug #695225 - No support for mp4 container in Handbrake](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=695225). There is a PPA with a fixed version of Handbrake, see [Handbrake Releases PPA](https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases). To enable it do:

```
sudo apt-get purge handbrake # remove any old versions
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk
```

---

To get the mp4 format to work you must go into preferences and disable the "ipod friendly mkv format" checkbox.

`handbrake-gtk` also available in [apps.ubuntu](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/handbrake-gtk/)

Comment: Partially successful. With the necessary "sudo" I followed the code above but still only had MPV.

Comment: I then removed all additional ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshot repositories (I had 3) via the Software & Updates GUI. I re-ran the last three commands but still on had MPV.

Comment: Finally, did all the above again but used Synaptic Package Manager to make absolutely sure it installed Handbrake from ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots. **SUCCESS!!!!**

Comment: Thank you. My way wasn't elegant and wouldn't have worked without your initial direction. I'm a bit worried that the code above didn't work cleanly and that this suggests that there are other underlying issues with my machine. Nevertheless I am extremely greatful. Thanks

Comment: I needed to add the repo, as given by bain, but needed to install "handbrake-gtk" instead of "handbrake".

Comment: handbrake-gtk also available in [apps.ubuntu](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/handbrake-gtk/)

Comment: Using this answer I am only able to convert to mkv or m4v. Not mp4.

Comment: @JonathanRogiest Disable Preferences -> "Use iPod/iTunes friendly .m4v file extension for MP4"

Comment: Astonishing that this workaround is still necessary.

Comment: I found simply renaming .m4v to mp4 and it works ok usually

Comment: m4v is the same thing as mp4, just different name.

Comment: This workaround is still necessary and still works in 2018. BTW, this seems to be a newer version of Handbrake, and you run with `gbh` instead of `handbrake`. Man I hate mkv. Has issues even in VLC sometimes, and nothing else supports it really.