# Linux/Ubuntu native (not Wine) alternative to DVD-Shrink, that can compress a DVD image to a smaller size to fit on a writeable DVD?

Tags: dvd, compression, alternative

An alternative to DVDShrink would be a program able to *shrink* a DVD movie to a smaller dimension that would fit a standard 4.7 dvd while optionally keeping the dvd-movies structure, menus etc. (that would not only be ***intended*** to do this, but that would also ***succeed***).

---

That was [already asked](https://askubuntu.com/q/129891/47206) but the answers are on Wine and others are old.

Any news on this?

---

Bound to be a duplicate - see [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/12119/47206).

### So, consider posting also under the older question to get the bounty.

Comment: @MadMike - you see, i just created this question to get attention for the older one, (link in the question) to which this is a duplicate. in fact the older answers are not outdated given the fact that no new solutions have emerged, but i wanted to verify that