# How to install k9copy in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I have learned from [here](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?64493-k9copy-fans) that k9copy, although not maintained anymore can be installed.

I think it is the package from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/k9copy/2.3.8-1)

But, following the instructions from there, I stumbled at the step where I have to run

> make -j4

I am trying to run it in the folder where I have already run the previous commands...

It looks like so.

[image]

There is a newer version [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/k9copy-reloaded/) but how to install that?

---

Edit after comment on getting deb from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/k9copy/2.3.8-3) and installing by command

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends k9copy_2.3.8-3_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for cip: 
(Reading database ... 315186 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack k9copy_2.3.8-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking k9copy (2.3.8-3) over (2.3.8-3) ...
dpkg: k9copy: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
 k9copy depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not installed.
 k9copy depends on libavcodec53 (>= 4:0.8-1~) | libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8-1~); however:
  Package libavcodec53 is not installed.
  Package libavcodec-extra-53 is not installed.
 k9copy depends on libavformat53 (>= 4:0.8-1~) | libavformat-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8-1~); however:
  Package libavformat53 is not installed.
  Package libavformat-extra-53 is not installed.
 k9copy depends on libavutil51 (>= 4:0.8-1~) | libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.8-1~); however:
  Package libavutil51 is not installed.
  Package libavutil-extra-51 is not installed.
 k9copy depends on libxine1 (>= 1.1.8); however:
  Package libxine1 is not installed.
 k9copy depends on phonon; however:
  Package phonon is not installed.

Setting up k9copy (2.3.8-3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
```

executing `/usr/bin/k9copy` it does not start

Comment: Might I suggest just installing the .deb from [this link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/k9copy/2.3.8-3)? (Under "Downloadable files")

Comment: @musher - i already have libavcodec54, while i'm asked for 53 in order to install the deb

Comment: You could try `dpkg -i --force-depends [deb file]`... if it hasn't been updated in a while it might just not know that 54 exists. However, on that note, it could also break things... so be careful.

Comment: @musher - i installed it with a lot of comments that i will post in question. but executing `/usr/bin/k9copy` it does not start

Comment: It looks like you're missing more than just libavcodec - do you have kde-runtime, libxine1.... all installed?

Comment: @musher - obviously not. but i got broken package now. please post as answer to give me more details on what should i do. otherwise this is too little info for my skill level :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**k9copy-reloaded** is supported; `.deb` files for *ubuntu Trusty, Utopic and Vivid, as well as Debian Jessie are available: [here](http://tomtomtom.org/k9copy-reloaded/en.html).

For 14.04 download the Trusty version.