# dvd95, alternative?

Tags: software-recommendation, 15.04, dvd

dvd95 was [removed from Vivid (15.04)](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+source/dvd95).

Do you know of any alternative as easy to use as that one (or maybe even easier) and that it is native for GTK environments or maybe that can be used via an easy CLI?

k9copy, as suggested below, pulls 126 packages of dependencies, marking it as **not** a serious alternative.
For example, installing a program for Windows through wine will take a lot less space and need less dependencies than k9copy.

This question was marked as a duplicate of [Is there an alternative to DVD-Shrink,[...]?](https://askubuntu.com/q/129891/29595).
I believe that this is not duplicate because of the comment to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/132303/29595) to that question:

> dvd95 does not work like dvdshrink;

I personally do not know DVD-Shrink, since I always used dvd95 and I would like to have an alternative to the latter, not to the first.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**   `dvd95`, `k9copy` and `dvd shrink` all perform pretty much the same task.

`dvd95` explanation can be found on its [homepage](http://dvd95.sourceforge.net/?)

`k9copy` explanation can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K9Copy)

`DVDShrink` explanation can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_Shrink)

**ALL OF THESE APPLICATIONS ARE USED TO CONVERT DVDS TO FIT TO A 4.7GB DVD**

**EDIT 2:**

**I was able to get `dvd95` to install into Ubuntu 15.04.**

For `dvd95` and Ubuntu 15.04 install, add the following lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
```

then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then run

```
sudo apt-get install dvd95
```

After `dvd95` is installed, remove the lines above or comment them out like below:

```
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
```

then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

so the repositories go back to normal so that you don't mess up updates in the future.

**K9COPY:**

I was able to get `k9copy` to install into Ubuntu 15.04.  It is the closet thing I can think of to `dvd95`.

I installed it by first downloading the `.deb` file from [here](http://tomtomtom.org/k9copy-reloaded/en.html).  I downloaded the`k9copy_3.0.3-1_vivid_amd64.deb` version.  Then I tried the install by typing in from the downloaded file location:

```
sudo dpkg -i k9copy_3.0.3-1_vivid_amd64.deb
```

which it failed about dependencies.  Immediately, I typed in:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

which then installed all the dependencies for `k9copy`.  Then I reran the `dpkg` install for `k9copy`:

```
sudo dpkg -i k9copy_3.0.3-1_vivid_amd64.deb
```

Hope this helps!

**NOTE:**  `k9copy` was written for the `K Desktop Environment`, that is why it pulls so many packages.

Comment: 126 packages of dependencies (`kate`, `kactivity`, `plasma` libraries, seriously?).

So, it is **NOT** a serious alternative to dvd95 (which is a native Gnome application).

Comment: BTW thanks for taking the time to answer. I updated the question stating this clearly, I would like something more native than k9copy for Unity.

Comment: I had many problems already when mixing DE's stuff that I would not like to risk another reinstallation :) dvd95 did not only shrink, it allowed you to choose what you want in it (audio tracks, subtitles, menus, and so on) and then changed the quality of the output to adjust to these settings. Does DVD shrink do it too?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try with DVD shrink asap and I'll keep you posted :)

Comment: @dadexix86 I updated my answer with the installation instructions for installing dvd95 into Ubuntu 15.04.